# boost log with boost 1.48 on OSX 10.7.2

Tags: c++, macos, boost

I pulled the latest BOOST log from https://boost-log.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/boost-log/trunk/ and tried building it against my current BOOST install (1.47) on osx lion (10.7.2) and it complained that it needed boost 1.48.

So I pulled down and built BOOST 1.48 which all went fine. I then updated my BOOST install , and ran bootstrap like this:

```
/bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=log --prefix=/usr/local 
    --includedir=/usr/local/include --libdir=/usr/local/lib
```

all fine at this point. Now however, when I run:

```
sudo ./b2
```

I get the following errors:

```
...found 2606 targets...
...updating 9 targets...
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/tick_count.o
libs/log/src/tick_count.cpp:220:5: error: #error Boost.Log: POSIX timers not 
supported on your platform

"g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -dynamic 
-no-cpp-    precomp -gdwarf-2 -fexceptions -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1
DBOOST_DATE_TIME_DYN_LINK=1 - DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK=1 
-DBOOST_LOG_BUILDING_THE_LIB=1 -DBOOST_LOG_DLL - DBOOST_LOG_USE_NATIVE_SYSLOG=1 
-DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_POSIX - DBOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL=1 -
DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o  "bin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/tick_count.o"  "libs/log/src/tick_count.cpp"

...failed darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/tick_count.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi>libboost_log.dylib for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi>tick_count.o...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_log.dylib for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin- 4.2.1/release/threading-multi>libboost_log.dylib...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi>libboost_log_setup.dylib for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi>libboost_log.dylib...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_log_setup.dylib for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi>libboost_log_setup.dylib...
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/link-static/threading-multi/tick_count.o
libs/log/src/tick_count.cpp:220:5: error: #error Boost.Log: POSIX timers not supported on  your platform

"g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -no-cpp-precomp -gdwarf-2 -fexceptions  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_LOG_BUILDING_THE_LIB=1 -DBOOST_LOG_USE_NATIVE_SYSLOG=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_POSIX -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/link-static/threading-multi/tick_count.o" "libs/log/src/tick_count.cpp"

...failed darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/link-static/threading-multi/tick_count.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_log.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/link-static/threading-multi>tick_count.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_log.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/link-static/threading-multi>tick_count.o...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_log.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_log.a...
...failed updating 2 targets...
...skipped 7 targets...
```

I looked at the BOOST log install stuff and there are a few directives but nothing obvious about this. Anyone give me a few clues about this? I'm finding nothing in stack overflow or on the web which does make me think i'm missing something. The posix timers not being supported is a pretty definitive message...

thanks in advance.

Comment: Briefly looking at the code it appears boost-log wasn't written to support Mac OS X which does not have an an implementation of Posix timers

Comment: @alanx: make it an answer, I will upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly looking at the code it appears boost-log wasn't written to support Mac OS X which does not have an an implementation of Posix timers.

Comment: On the boost 1.48 page it says that it compiles with Mac OS X gcc 4.2.1 and 4.4.4 so should be able to run on OSX : http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_48_0.html

Comment: As far as I know boost-log isn't an official library yet, thus has no guarantee that it will compile/function under Mac OS X

Comment: Clarifying: boost-log isn't an official boost library yet.

Comment: Rapidly coming to the same conclusion - seems a shame as it was working fine under 1_47, and right now, i'm struggling to find a previous version of boost.log - the trunk version on source forge is v 1.0 which seems to be the 1_48 version now

Comment: You're right, alanxz. Boost Log uses the Darwin equivalent as of r655, which is `mach_absolute_time()`.

Comment: yep - I give up. Easy enough to write a logger class for my needs so I did that. Hopefully it will get fixed in a future build as it has some useful stuff in there for managing size/time etc.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been fixed in r655.

The problem is that Darwin does not feature the POSIX extension which provides `clock_gettime()`. However, Darwin does have a high-resolution monotic clock available in `mach/mach_time.h` called `mach_absolute_time()`. As of r655, Boost Log uses this function on Mac OS.

If you want to install the most recent Boost version without any pain, plus enjoy the benefits of C++11, check out [my custom Portfile](https://github.com/mavam/macports-overlay/tree/master/devel/boost). For example, it allows you to install Boost as follows:

```
sudo port install boost +cxx11 +log +debug +no_single
```

where the `+log` variant pulls the most recent SVN version.